# Jenkins key-value variable or using a variable to define another

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I'm setting up a centralized build system where several projects get "packaged". The project can be selected using a choice parameter, and based on it I'm building the SVN checkout path. The repository is the same, but each app has a slightly different path, eg:

- app 1 resides in ../libs/App1..
- app 2 resides in ../tools/App2..
- etc

My problem is that I need to somehow match the app name with its location.

The first thought that came to mind was a key-value parameter but I have yet to find a plugin that permits it.

The second one was to define some environmental variables within a file (there are 2-3 plugins that do it) and then use the value selected in the choice parameter to as the key for the env var. Is this achievable in any way?

Kind regards

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't create separate jobs for each application?

Comment: Yes, we have about 30 components and we'll probably have more. The build process is similar to all, hence it is rather redundant and difficult to maintain. That's why I'm trying to get it centralized :)

Comment: Can't you implement this with parameterized builds: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: I had asked the question because at that time I was not able to find a way to do it. If you have something in mind please do share, because I'm still interested.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few years :-) and on an unrelated topic, I found the [Active choices plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) also known as / forked from [uno choice plugin](https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin) which allows to define parameters which dynamically update when changing other parameters:

**1)** define an *active choice parameter* named `states` with the following groovy-script content

```
return[
'Sao Paulo',
'Rio de Janeiro',
'Parana',
'Acre'
]
```

**2)** Define an *active choice reactive parameter* named `cities` which reacts to changes in the first parameter's value, with the following groovy-script content:

```
if (States.equals("Sao Paulo")) {
  return ["Barretos", "Sao Paulo", "Itu"]
} else if (States.equals("Rio de Janeiro")) {
  return ["Rio de Janeiro", "Mangaratiba"]
} else if (States.equals("Parana")) {
  return ["Curitiba", "Ponta Grossa"]
} else if (States.equals("Acre")) {
  return ["Rio Branco", "Acrelandia"]
} else {
  return ["Unknown state"]
}
```

Thus, each time the `state` changes, then the list of selectable `cities` will be updated accordingly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) together with [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) in order to set up an environment variable (say `APP_PATH`) that depends on your build parameters before any other build steps. You then use `${APP_PATH}` whenever you need it in your build.