# How To Set Up PowerMockito To Verify Different Types of Methods Are Called?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Please provide minimal examples of using PowerMockito to test public, public static, private, and private static methods.

Comment: You've forgotten the question...

Comment: @Morfic it's in the title, if I set this up wrong please provide specific instructions.

Comment: I noticed the title, but I find it difficult to understand where you're having trouble. Are you getting an exception? Is something not working as expected? Etc...

Comment: It's meant to be an "answer your own question" type of thing. I'm demonstrating how to use Powermock for the four different scenarios listed. I had to figure this out and thought the community might benefit. I see your point though and will modify accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, in this case you can post it just like a regular question, then write your own answer and choose it as the correct one so others will easily spot the solution. Depending on your reputation you may have to wait a while, but it is possible and encouraged to do to. I had [one or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636547/jenkins-key-value-variable-or-using-a-variable-to-define-another) myself :-) Cheers

Comment: This should be arranged correctly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an extremely stripped down example ("[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)") of using PowerMockito to verify four types of methods have been called from another method: public, public static, private, and private static.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(com.dnb.cirrus.core.authentication.TestableTest.Testable.class)

public class TestableTest {
    public static class Testable {
        public void a() {
            b();
            c();
            d();
            e();
        }
        public void b() {
        }
        public static void c() {
        }
        private void d() {
        }
        private static void e() {
        }
    }

    Testable testable;

    // Verify that public b() is called from a()
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        testable = Mockito.spy(new Testable());
        testable.a();
        Mockito.verify(testable).b();
    }
    // Verify that public static c() is called from a()
    @Test
    public void testC() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Testable.class);
        testable = new Testable();
        testable.a();
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
        Testable.c();
    }
    // Verify that private d() is called from a()
    @Test
    public void testD() throws Exception {
        testable = PowerMockito.spy(new Testable());
        testable.a();
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(testable).invoke("d");
    }
    // Verify that private static e() is called from a()
    @Test
    public void testE() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Testable.class);
        testable = new Testable();
        testable.a();
        PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(Testable.class).invoke("e");
    }
}
```

Some pitfalls to be aware of:

1. PowerMockito and Mockito both implement spy() as well as other methods. Make sure to use the correct class for the situation.
2. Incorrectly set up PowerMockito tests often pass. Be sure the test can fail when it should (checked for in the above code by commenting out "testable.a()").
3. Overridden PowerMockito methods take either Class or Object as parameters which are used in static and non-static contexts respectively. Make sure to use the correct type for the context.